# Adjective to describe a piece of text that came out too big

Tags: word-request, adjectives

Which adjective would be suitable right after "too" to describe a piece of text that took too much space in a document?

> Your descriptions are very clear, but too _________ .

or

> Your descriptions came out too ____________ .

(using "big" sounds a bit blunt to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on the assumption that the text is not concise and has too much information (i.e., it has something to do with the content). I am not sure if it is a matter of "space" which has more to do with reducing font size, changing fonts, reducing line spacing, etc.

It should be

> Your descriptions are very clear, but **it's** (= the chapter/section/argument) too _________ .

or

> Your descriptions are very clear, but **they are** (= the descriptions/arguments) too _________ .

One option is to use "verbose". This may require slight changes to your sentence.

From Cambridge

> Verbose (adj): using or containing more words than are necessary
>   - a verbose explanation/report/speech/style

If you rephrase your sentence, you can use the noun too.

> verbosity (n): the quality of being verbose (= using too many words)
>
> - Knowing they wouldn't welcome too much verbosity, he simplified his talk.
> - The message is clear and concise and displays no verbosity.

You can also say "this section is too wordy" or "this section is too long".

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain, please, why I can't jump directly to "too" right after "but"? In other words, why should I say "it's" or "they are" first?

Comment: That is because of the comma before the conjunction. If you have a comma there, then the next clause needs a subject. Those are two independent sentences - (1) *"Your descriptions are very clear"* and (2) *"These descriptions are too wordy"*. When you put them together, you get - *"Your descriptions are very clear, but **they are** too wordy"*. Without the comma, you don't need a subject in the second clause - *"Your descriptions are very clear but too wordy"*. This is not a rule. Its just a guideline. In a compound sentence, if the independent clauses are small, then the comma can be dropped.

Comment: See this [Comma Before And](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-and/)

Comment: WOW! Thank you. Very informative.